# Why does a file written out encoded as UTF-8 end up being ISO-8859-1 instead?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I am reading an **ISO-8859-1** encoded text file, transcoding it to UTF-8, and writing out a different file as **UTF-8**. However, when I inspect the output file, it is still encoded as **ISO-8859-1**! What am I doing wrong?

Here is my ruby class:

```
module EF
  class Transcoder

    # app_path ......... Path to the java console application (InferEncoding.jar) that infers the character encoding.
    # target_encoding .. Transcodes the text loaded from the file into this encoding.
    attr_accessor :app_path, :target_encoding

    def initialize(consoleAppPath)
      @app_path = consoleAppPath
      @target_encoding = "UTF-8"
    end

    def detect_encoding(filename)
      encoding = `java -jar #{@app_path} \"#{filename}\"`
      encoding = encoding.strip
    end

    def transcode(filename)
      original_encoding = detect_encoding(filename)
      content = File.open(filename, "r:#{original_encoding}", &:read)
      content = content.force_encoding(original_encoding)
      content.encode!(@target_encoding, :invalid => :replace)
    end

    def transcode_file(input_filename, output_filename)
      content = transcode(input_filename)
      File.open(output_filename, "w:#{@target_encoding}") do |f| 
        f.write content 
      end
    end

  end

end
```

By way of explanation, @app_path is the path to a Java jar file. This console application will read a text file and tell me what its current encoding is (printing it to stdout). It uses the ubiquitous ICU library. (I tried using the ruby gem charlock-holmes, but I cannot get it to compile on Windows for MINGW. The Java bindings to ICU are good, so I wrote a Java application instead.)

To call the above class, I do this in **irb**:

```
require_relative 'transcoder'

tc = EF::Transcoder.new("C:/Users/paul.chernoch/Documents/java/InferEncoding.jar")

tc.detect_encoding "C:/temp/infer-encoding-test/ISO-8859-1.txt"

tc.transcode_file("C:/temp/infer-encoding-test/ISO-8859-1.txt", "C:/temp/infer-encoding-test/output-utf8.txt")

tc.detect_encoding "C:/temp/infer-encoding-test/output-utf8.txt"
```

1. The file ISO-8859-1.txt is encoded like it sounds. I used Notepad++ to write the file using that encoding.
2. I used my Java application to test the file. It concurs that it is in **ISO-8859-1** format.
3. I also created a file in Notepad++ and saved it as UTF-8. I then verified using my java app that it was in **UTF-8**.
4. After I perform the above in **irb**, I used my java app to test the output file and it says the format is still **ISO-8859-1**.

What am I doing wrong? If you hard-code the method detect_encoding to return "ISO-8859-1", you do not need my java application to replicate the part that reads the file.

Any solution must **NOT** use **charlock-holmes**.

Comment: What are the contents of your test file? I suspect that this is working correctly, but that ICU reports a file that only contains ASCII characters as ISO-8859-1. Do you have bytes > 127 in the file, and do they remain unchanged in the output file?

Comment: I do not have such characters in the file. I have been searching for useful test files in different encodings but have not yet had success.